# Using fillna to replace missing data

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

When I am trying to use fillna to replace NaNs in the columns with means, the NaNs changed from `float64` to `object`, showing:

> bound method Series.mean of 0 NaN\n1

Here is the code:

```
mean = df['texture_mean'].mean
df['texture_mean'] = df['texture_mean'].fillna(mean)`
```

Comment: `mean` is a method, so you should call it using parenthesis `mean = df['texture_mean'].mean()`.
BTW, the stacktrace indicates the line where the error raises. Using this information is a good hint on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `mean = df['texture_mean'].mean`. This is where the problem lies. The following code will work -

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'texture_mean':[2,4,None,6,1,None],'A':[1,2,3,4,5,None]}) # Example 
df
     A  texture_mean
0  1.0           2.0
1  2.0           4.0
2  3.0           NaN
3  4.0           6.0
4  5.0           1.0
5  NaN           NaN

df['texture_mean']=df['texture_mean'].fillna(df['texture_mean'].mean())

df
     A  texture_mean
0  1.0          2.00
1  2.0          4.00
2  3.0          3.25
3  4.0          6.00
4  5.0          1.00
5  NaN          3.25
```

In case you want to replace all the NaNs with the respective means of that column in all columns, then just do this -

```
df=df.fillna(df.mean())
df
     A  texture_mean
0  1.0          2.00
1  2.0          4.00
2  3.0          3.25
3  4.0          6.00
4  5.0          1.00
5  3.0          3.25
```

Let me know if this is what you want.